# How to search in Chrome for exact Unicode characters?

Tags: google-chrome, search, unicode

I am looking for a pattern such as `aṣṭi`, but Google Chrome finds every `asti` including those without the diacritics. How do I get the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to only find the exact matches?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the regular search supports that. What you *can* do is enable the Developer Tools, Inspect Elements (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), *then* Find (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and enter your query in the search bar that appears at the bottom. A popover will show you where the hit on the page is, and it searches for exact matches, taking into account diacritics.

[image]